# Moving a method between parent/child interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have the following inheritance structure:

```
interface A
{ 
   void Foo();
}
interface B : A
{
}
```

And I realise that the only places where `Foo()` is actually implemented (i.e., not empty) is in the classes which are implementing B.

If I move `Foo` from A to B, will I have to recompile all those implementing classes, and, more importantly, what about all the assemblies which are *using* those implementations?

*(I know I can just try this myself, and see, but I'd also like some 'insight' into what's happening)*

Comment: Update: tried on some test projects. If I call `Foo` directly on the instance of the class which implements `B`, I don't need to recompile, but if I call it through the interface, I do need to recompile. Shame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface definition will be changing in a non backward compatible way, so you will have to recompile other assemblies as well, and if some code is calling `Foo` on `A` objects, you will have to rewrite that part of code as well.

Answer (score 1):

For any files/classes in your solution: yes. If class `A` is actually in a .dll library, yes also, and you will have to recompile the library and update your references. I don't see why this is a big deal, though. C# compiles pretty fast and is smart about its compiling. (By the way, every time you run your program, doesn't it build anyways?)

Comment: > "By the way, every time you run your program, doesn't it build anyways?" - er, nope!

Comment: Oops - I meant "every time you build your program, doesn't it compile"

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a versioning problem. The current Interface is 'out of date' and then new 'improved' interface should replace it.

This off course depends a lot of how its used.